# Will I be able to gain all of the soul matrix skills?

Tags: soul-hackers-2

When you unlock a soul matrix gate, you're able to choose an unlockable skill for a teammate. The issue is, there are multiple to choose from and each one you pick, unlocks a new set of skills. Am I going to be able to unlock all of these skills by the end of the game or are some of these skills unattainable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No spoiler answer: Yes, eventually. But don't worry about it on a single playthrough. Just pick the ones you like or think will be the most helpful. There also is no trophy for selecting all of them in case you're worried about that.

Spoiler answer:

> Yes - with multiple playthroughs. There are 5 levels, you can get to the end of the 4th level of some teammates during your first playthrough. You'll have to play again with the NG+ addition of added soul gain in order to reach the 5th and final level.